# Updating data in MySQL database based on checked dynamic checkboxes in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry about my question, but I'm starting with PHP and I want to ask you for a help with my problem.

In my web application I work with a table, which has a dynamic count of rows based on the number of rows in a source table in MySQL database. In the application should be a checkbox in each row of the table. After clicking on the submitt button there should be update of records in the source table and it should be update just of these records where the checkboxes were checked.

The table in the application looks simillar like in the picture.

[image]

The primary key in the source table is in the column NUMBER. As a first try I simulated that after clicking on submitt button there will be shown the msgbox with the values from the column NUMBER for the rows, where the checkboxes were checked.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>APLICATIONa</title>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelected() {
        //Reference the Table.
        var grid = document.getElementById("Table");

        //Reference the CheckBoxes in Table.
        var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        var message = "\n";

        //Loop through the CheckBoxes.
        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
                var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;

                message += "   " + row.cells[1].innerHTML;
                message += "\n";
            }
        }

        //Display selected Row data in Alert Box.
        alert(message);
    }
</script>


  </head>
<body>
  <?php

$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_03_2020");

          echo "<br><form action='main.php' method='POST'>";
          echo "<input type='submit' name='button' value='Get Selected' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='GetSelected()' />";
          echo "<table id = 'Table' border='0px' bordercolor='silver' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='2' width='100%'>";
          echo "<tr bgcolor='#EEEEEE' height='45px'><th></th><th><b>NUMBER</b></th><th><b>NAME</b></th></tr>";
          while ($zaznam=MySQL_Fetch_Array($values)):
          echo "<tr onmouseover=\"highlight_row(this, 1, '#F2F2F2');\" onmouseout=\"highlight_row(this, 0, '#F2F2F2');\">";


 echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' ></td>";
echo "<td><font color='red'>".$zaznam["number"]."</font></td>";
echo "<td>".$zaznam["name"]."</td>";



          echo "</tr>";
          endwhile;
          echo "</table><br>";
          echo "</form>";

        ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

The msgbox is just an illustration. Instead of msgbox, I need that after clicking on the submit button, there should be an update for these records in the source table, where the checkboxes were selected (so of these records, which are now shown in the msgbox). So I need something like:

```
"UPDATE table_03_2020 SET column1 = 'xy' where NUMBER in ('values of NUMBER from rows, where the checkbox was checked)"
```

There'll be also a second submit button and after clicking on it, there should be another different update. So after clicking on the second button, I need something like:

```
"UPDATE table_03_2020 SET column1 = 'ab' where NUMBER in ('values of NUMBER from rows, where the checkbox was checked)"
```

I'm sorry if my question is not so clear, but I'd really appreciate any help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a value to the checkboxes, like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cbox[]' value='{$zaznam["number"]}' >
```

When the form is submitted the `cbox` variable will contain an array of these numbers, which means that you can process them like this:

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';   #your database connection!!!

    $sql='update table_03_2020 set `column1`="XY" where `column2` in ( ? )';

    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
    $ids=implode(',',$_POST['cbox']);
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$ids);
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

Note that the above has not been tested so there might be errors but I hope it'll give the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add key values with the number to the cbox form variable:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='cbox[" .$zaznam["number"]. "]' ></td>";
```

Then use the following PHP to get the number list.

```
if (isset($_POST["cbox"])) {
    $checked = array();
    foreach($_POST["cbox"] as $number => $val) {
        $checked[] = addslashes($number);
    }
    $checked_list = implode(",", $checked);
}
```

The addslashes function is for SQL Injection protection.
This will create a list with comma separated numbers.
Than, you can insert it in the the SQL query.

```
UPDATE table_03_2020 SET column1 = 'xy' where NUMBER in ('. $checked_list .')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I tried to improve the part of the code to:

```
   echo "<input type='submit' name='buttonupdate' value='Get Selected' >";
          echo "<table id = 'Table' border='0px' bordercolor='silver' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='2' width='100%'>";
          echo "<tr bgcolor='#EEEEEE' height='45px'><th></th><th><b>NUMBER</b></th><th><b>NAME</b></th></tr>";
          while ($zaznam=MySQL_Fetch_Array($values)):
          echo "<tr onmouseover=\"highlight_row(this, 1, '#F2F2F2');\" onmouseout=\"highlight_row(this, 0, '#F2F2F2');\">";


if ($_POST["buttonupdate"])  {
if (isset($_POST["cbox"])) {
    $checked = array();
    foreach($_POST["cbox"] as $number => $val) {
        $checked[] = addslashes($number);
    }
    $checked_list = implode(",", $checked);
}
}

 echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='cbox[" .$zaznam["cflot"]. "]' ></td>";
```

It didn't work, there was no update. Did I edited the code incorrectly?

Actually I forgot to mention the second button, so I edited my first post. Would it be possible to distinguish between the first and the second button? Thank you very much for any help.